# How to acces values of Dropdown in a table cell

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML-table with some dropdowns in the cells. I would like to access the options of my dropdown like I tried below. How can I do that? My JavaScript doesn't seem to work.

```
<table id = "xy">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>--Please Select--</option>
          <option>value 1</option>
          <option>value 2</option>
          <option>value 3</option>
       </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
       <select>
          <option>--Please Select--</option>
          <option>value 1</option>
          <option>value 2</option>
          <option>value 3</option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ...
        var table = document.getElementById("xy");

        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
             alert(row.cells[0].innerHTML.options[0].value);
             alert(row.cells[1].innerHTML.options[0].value);
        }
        ...
    </script>
```

Comment: innerHTML returns the serialized HTML code, in other words a string and not a HTML node. You could access it like this: `row.cells[0].children[0].options[0].value` However I would not recommend selecting elements like this. Instead make use of [document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: works, is it possible to get the options as a array? Something like this: `var myArray = row.cells[0].children[0].options` instead of access only a single value?

Comment: So you want an array of the selected `<option>` elements' values? What about the case where the user leaves the default `<option>` selected (the `--Please Select--` `<option>`)? And when do you want to retrieve these values, on page-load, in response to user-interaction (after each `<select>` is changed, after a `<button>` or `<a>` is pressed), on `<form>` submission?

Comment: @Justin You can convert the HTMLCollection to an array via `Array.from(row.cells[0].children[0].options)`. But if you just want to iterate over them you can also use a simple [for of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all `tr` elements in the table:

```
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('#xy tr');
```

Then read `value`s of each `select` in each row:

```
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#xy tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { //iterate over rows
        var selects = rows[i].querySelectorAll('select');
        for (var j = 0; j < selects.length; j++) { //iterate over selects in a row
            console.log('Row number: ' + i);
            console.log(selects[j].value);
        }
    }
```

**Example:**

```js
function readValues() {
    var rows = document.querySelectorAll('#xy tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var selects = rows[i].querySelectorAll('select');
        for (var j = 0; j < selects.length; j++) {
            console.log('Row number: ' + i);
            console.log(selects[j].value);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<table id = "xy">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select>
          <option>--Please Select--</option>
          <option>value 1</option>
          <option>value 2</option>
          <option>value 3</option>
       </select>
      </td>
      <td>
       <select>
          <option>--Please Select--</option>
          <option>value 1</option>
          <option>value 2</option>
          <option>value 3</option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
       <select>
          <option>--Please Select--</option>
          <option>value 1</option>
          <option>value 2</option>
          <option>value 3</option>
      </select>
     </td>
      <td>
       <select>
          <option>--Please Select--</option>
          <option>value 1</option>
          <option>value 2</option>
          <option>value 3</option>
      </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button onclick="readValues()">Read values</button>
```

Comment: I dont want ALL select elements. I would like to have all the Selects in a current row i'm interating. Like row.cells[0].querySelectorAll('select')... but this is not working